# Can Eclipse set a breakpoint on a package?

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I wish to see if any code in a package (say `org.xmlcml.svg2xml.action`) is called in my current JUnit tests. There are over 30 classes. Is there a way to set a breakpoint on the package or do I have to set breakpoints for each class?

Comment: I would execute the test with a code coverage tool, and see if any line of any class of your package has been executed.

Comment: Understood. I'm not currently running one... but this may be one answer